# New to python. I need a simple way to input a range with increments into a function

Tags: python-2.7

The problem with the following is that I want instead of Iext=200e-3, I'd like it to be a range from 0 to 200e-3 in increments of 1e-3. Then I'd like to use this new Iext to determine firingrate for each increment, perhaps with somehow wrapping the code with:

```
def firingrate (Iext , tau_ref ):

...

r = len( spiketimes )/T*1 e3 # Convert kHz to Hz
return r
```

CODE:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tau=20 #ms
EL=-65 #mV
V0=EL
T=100000 #ms
dt=.1 #ms
R=100 #MOhm
Vth=-55 #mV
Vreset=EL
tau_ref=3 #ms
Iext=200e-3 #nA

def f(V):
    return (-V+EL+R*(Iext+400e-3*np.random.normal()))/tau

t=np.linspace(0,T,int(T/dt)+1)
V=np.zeros(len(t))

spiketimes=[]
is_refractory=False
refractory_end=0
V[0]=V0

for i in xrange(1, len(t)):
    if is_refractory:
        V[i]=V[i-1]
        if t[i]>=refractory_end:
            is_refractory=False
    V[i]=V[i-1]+f(V[i-1])*dt
    if V[i]>=Vth:
        V[i]=Vreset
        spiketimes.append(t[i-1])
        is_refractory=True
        refractory_end=t[i]+tau_ref

firingrate=len(spiketimes)/T*1e3
print("Firing rate={} Hz").format(firingrate)
```

Comment: There is not enough context or explanation here to tell what you're trying or hope to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, (x)range only takes integer arguments and refuses to deal with floats. However, to create a range from 0 to 0.2 by increments of 0.001, we can simply step through integers then multiply:

```
for increment in xrange(201):
    increment *= 0.001
    # do something with increment
```